# Uploading files using requests and send extra data

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to upload a file using [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I need to upload a PDF file and at the same time send some other data to the form like the author's name.

I tried this:

```
requests.get(url, files = {"file":open("file.txt"), "author" : "me" })
```

But it doesn't send data to the form.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid please look at the question again

Answer (score 32):

So I understand that you want to upload to a URL, a pdf file along with some extra parameters.

First error that you have is you are using `.get()` and not `.post()`.

I am using samples from the [documentation](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/), which you should go through.  This should get you started:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': open('somefile.pdf', 'rb')}
>>> values = {'author': 'John Smith'}
>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=values)
```

Comment: I am asked to do this `Make a multipart post request to http://server-url/oauth/. with the following form fields. AUTHOR, PDF FILE`

Comment: should I add the file in `data` parameter dict.?/?

Comment: No, add it to the `files` parameter, the `data` parameter is for form data.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - can you also advise how to retrieve this data in an endpoint. I am using flask and get the file contents using `request.data`. How can I get the additional data (values)?

Comment: use `request.form` in flask endpoint to retrieve the data.