# upload file to server not working in python

Tags: python

I'd like to upload files to a server using python. That means in this case that when I write http://example.com/files/ in my browser I'd like to see de.txt there in the list of files. How should I change this script to be working? When I run it, python shell writes out nothing, only the >>>.

Thanks in advance!

```
import requests

url = 'http://example.com/files/'
user, password = 'ex', 'ample'

files = {'upload_file': open(r'C:\Users\example\Desktop\code\de.txt','rb')}

r = requests.post(url,  auth=(user, password), files=files)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

Writing a file across network

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = 'http://example.com/files/'
user, password = 'ex', 'ample'

files = {'file': ('de.txt', open('de.txt', 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data', {'Expires': '0'})}

r = requests.post(url,  auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, password), files=files)
```

For reference use [Python Request documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Comment: ValueError: cannot encode objects that are not 2-tuples

Comment: there is something else which is causing this error. can you share your code

Comment: I think you are get error because of `auth=(user, password)` this syntax

Comment: import requests
from StringIO import StringIO
buffer = StringIO()

url = 'http://example.com/files/'
user, password = 'ex', 'ample'

buffer.write(open(r'C:\Users\example\Desktop\code\de.txt','rb').read()) 

r = requests.post(url,  auth=(user, password), files=buffer.getvalue())

Comment: @Marci it's same code that I have give you in answer.?

Comment: @Marci for more information read [Request Auth](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)

Comment: thank you, but are  you sure thatauth=(user, password)
causes the error? The request.get  handles that perfectly

Comment: yes, because I text `buffer.getvalue()` part is working perfectly fine

Comment: tried with auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass') but didn't work either, do you have an idea how i could make sure using 2-tuples?

Comment: read this [Python request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)