# Django REST API : Create object from python file

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm looking for developping `Django REST API` from my web application and I would like to try creating object through the API. Mainly if my process is well-implemented.

I'm using a python file in order to make that.

This is my file :

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8000/Api/identification/create/'

data = {
    "Etat": "Vivant",
    "Civilite": "Monsieur",
    "Nom": "creation",
    "Prenom": "via-api",
    "Sexe": "Masculin",
    "Statut": "Célibataire",
    "DateNaissance": "1991-11-23",
    "VilleNaissance": "STRASBOURG",
    "PaysNaissance": "FR",
    "Nationalite1": "FRANCAISE",
    "Nationalite2": "",
    "Profession": "Journaliste",
    "Adresse": "12, rue des fleurs",
    "Ville": "STRASBOURG",
    "Zip": 67000,
    "Pays": "FR",
    "Mail": "",
    "Telephone": "",
    "Image": "http://localhost:8000/media/pictures/HH_Hh_19212-00001-979812-2_ShUDIk8.jpg",
    "CarteIdentite": "http://localhost:8000/media/Carte_Identite/carte_ID_lzpOI41_WOnC9WH.gif"
    }

response = requests.post(url, data=data)

print (response.text)
```

I'm confusing if I have to use `post` or `put`, but anyway, I don't overcome to create my object. If I make the process directly through the API, it works, but not with a pythonic file.

Any idea ?

**EDIT :**

For example, it works with these files :

```
#API_list.py
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8000/Api/Identification/'

response = requests.get(url)

print (response.text)
```

and

```
#API_details.py
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8000/Api/Identification/26/'

response = requests.get(url)

print (response.text)
```

and

```
#API_edit.py
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/Identity/26/edit/'

data = {
    "Ville": "STRASBOURG",
    "Zip": 67000,
    "Pays": "FR",
    "Adresse": "12, rue de la mésange",
    "Telephone": "0388603938",
    "Mail": "ceciestuntest@datasystems.fr",
}

response = requests.put(url, data=data)

print (response.text)
```

Comment: No server code? No error message? No traceback?

Comment: No, because I'm executing my script outside of Django perimeter. I created a file `API_create.py` with the content above, and I make : `python API_create.py`. It works with other files : API_list, API_details, etc ... But I don't overcome to create an object thanks to this method.

Comment: post the create code so that its easier to understand, and also any tracebacck

Comment: @Exprator I can post the create code, but I don't have Traceback because I'm executing my python file with my Terminal ^^

Comment: You probably have to use `post` to create a new object, so your code looks good. I think you should `print(response)` to get the status code. There is probably something wrong in the posted data that explains the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that your your url is correct?

Comment: @luc I'm getting `<Response [400]>` so I have to see what is this error. But you're right, the url had a little mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to use post to create a new object, so your code looks good.

There is probably something wrong in the posted data that explains the problem.

I think you should `print(response)` to get the status code. That will help to understand. Look also at your server logs, that may tell you what is wrong.

Maybe there is also something wrong in your url. If you are using a 'Django-rest-framework' viewset, the url for a create is probably something like `http://localhost:8000/Api/identification/`

Comment: I'm getting this error with `print(response.text)` : `{"Image":["Data is not a file Check the formulary encoding type."]}`. It's pretty weird because the file is good and the path too : `"Image": "/Users/valentin/Desktop/Django/DatasystemsCORE/Media/pictures/photo.jpg",`

Comment: @Deadpool The server expects a file and you give it a link to a file. May be this will help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567429/117092

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to @luc answer :

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8000/Api/Identification/create/'

filename1 = '/Users/valentin/Desktop/Django/DatasystemsCORE/Media/pictures/photo.jpg'
filename2 = '/Users/valentin/Desktop/Django/DatasystemsCORE/Media/Carte_Identite/carte_ID.gif'
files = {'Image' : open(filename1,'rb'), 'CarteIdentite': open(filename2,'rb')}

data = {
    "Etat": "Vivant",
    "Civilite": "Monsieur",
    "Nom": "creation",
    "Prenom": "via-api",
    "Sexe": "Masculin",
    "Statut": "Célibataire",
    "DateNaissance": "1991-11-23",
    "VilleNaissance": "STRASBOURG",
    "PaysNaissance": "FR",
    "Nationalite1": "FRANCAISE",
    "Nationalite2": "",
    "Profession": "JJJ",
    "Adresse": "12, rue des fleurs",
    "Ville": "STRASBOURG",
    "Zip": 67000,
    "Pays": "FR",
    "Mail": "",
    "Telephone": ""
    }

response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)

print(response.text)
```