# How to execute curl command from python script?

Tags: python, hadoop, curl, scripting, apache-ranger

I was running curl command from unix shell for adding the users in ranger (hadoop) but I want to run the same curl command from python script, How to achieve the same ? Please find below curl  command for the same :
**curl -u admin:admin  -v -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://:6080/service/xusers/secure/users -d @/tmp/userfile.json**

Comment: How to provide credentials like here I am providing admin:admin with curl ?

Comment: Note that calling the curl command external to your python script may not be the best design.  If you want to use the request api provided by Python language then see here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload