# Requests and Django, "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received InMemoryUploadedFile" when uploading file

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

When making an API (Django 1.11) request with `requests`, I'm unable to make a successful POST request that contains both a file and a ForeignKey in the body.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    url(r'^dataset/visual$', api_views.VisualList.as_view(), name='api-visual'),
    ....
```

]

**models.py**

```
class Visual(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Visuals"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    visual = models.FileField(upload_to='visuals/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document) <--- LOOK HERE

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
class VisualList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser, FileUploadParser)
    queryset = Visual.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VisualSerializer


class VisualDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    queryset = Visual.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VisualSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
class VisualSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Visual
        fields = '__all__'
```

**my_requests.py**

```
response = requests.request(
    'POST',
    'http://127.0.0.1/api/dataset/visual',
    files={'name': 'Hello World', 'description': 'from API', 'document': 5,
           'visual': ('hello_world.html', open('HELLOWORLD.html', 'rb'))})
```

When I set `document = models.ForeignKey(Document, null=True)` in **models.py**, and I remove the `document` key from the `files` param, I am able to upload the file just fine.

However, when I include `document` and make it a mandatory field, I get the error:

```
"Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received InMemoryUploadedFile"
```

It definitely looks like I'm passing the correct type for `pk` as an integer of a `document` that definitely exists. I have other models referencing `document` as a ForeignKey as well and I am able to make API POSTs with a integer value for the `document` key as expected. **THE ONLY DIFFERENCE** seems to be that I'm also trying to upload a file with this endpoint.

I feel like I'm missing something silly but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: using same name for the model and its attribute is not the greatest idea. Rename your file fields something else.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll change the attr to something else

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't send form data this way.
In order to send data along with files, they need to be separated:

```
response = requests.request(
    'POST',
    'http://127.0.0.1/api/dataset/visual',
    data={
        'name': 'Hello World',
        'description': 'from API',
        'document': 5,
    },
    files={
        'visual': ('hello_world.html', open('HELLOWORLD.html', 'rb')),
    }
)
```

Comment: That is what I tried initially and it makes sense, but then I get I got: {"name":["This field is required."],"document":["This field is required."]}. Which leads me to believe that it's only accepting the 'files' param. I read another SO question's accepted answer that said to include everything with the 'files' dict so that's what I did. I'll try to find the thread

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload, this should be fine. If you still get validation error, ensure the request has the correct content type (ie, multipart)