# POST request for .txt file

Tags: python, fastapi

I can't write a function, that can get a .txt file through POST-request.

I have a .txt file that contains phrase: Hello World!

server side:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File
from starlette.requests import Request
import io

app = FastAPI()
@app.post("/post_text_file")
def text_function(request: Request,
            file: bytes = File(...)):
    text = open(io.BytesIO(file), "r").read()
    return text  # Hello World!
```

client side:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8000/post_text_file'
r = requests.post(url,data=open('Hello World.txt'))
```

after run command uvicorn main:app and run a code in a client side I get next answer:

On the client side: {'detail': 'There was an error parsing the body'}

On the server side: "POST /post_text_file HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload

Comment: There are proposed to send a dictionary {"data": open('text_file.txt, "rb"}. But required to send a .txt file, not json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `files` parameter for [requests.post](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) you can use it to send files like this:

```py
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8000/post_text_file"
fin = open('Hello World.txt', 'rb')
files = {'file': fin}
try:
    r = requests.post(url, files=files)
finally:
    fin.close()
```

And usually the file sent with your request is accessible with `request.files` as a dictionary of files uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you don't have *python-multipart* installed. So be sure you have done:

```
pip install python-multipart
```