# POST request works from POSTMAN but not in flask

Tags: python, api, flask, python-requests, postman

Assume api url is https://34.35.36.37:8000/api

Sent a POST request from postman app which is successfull
[image]

[image]

The attached file(key = user_image) is a .jpg file

On the server side (https://34.35.36.37:8000/api):

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def api():
    print("check1")
    user_image = request.files['user_image']
    print("check2")
    return "some text"
```

But when I try a post request using a flask app in which a form is displayed to upload an image which is then sent to the api url, there is an error

```
api_url = "https://34.35.36.37:8000/api"
content_type = 'application/json' 
headers = {'Content-Type': content_type}

class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
    user_image = FileField('Upload an image',validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'], u'Image only!'), FileRequired(u'File was empty!')])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    form = UploadForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        payload = {}
        files = [
          ('user_image', form.data['user_image'])
        ]
        #response = requests.post(api_url, data={'user_image': form.data['user_image']}, headers=headers, verify=False)
        response = requests.request("POST", api_url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files, verify=False)
        print(response.text)
        return 'some text'

     return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

When checked on the server side, the line `print('check1')` is executed but the line `print('check2')` is not executed.

I think the error is with the following 2 lines which involves sending image to the api url in the post request

Line1:

```
files = [
              ('user_image', form.data['user_image'])
            ]
```

Line2:

```
response = requests.request("POST", api_url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files, verify=False)
```

Comment: Looks like the `files` parameter sends the data as a stream and you need to do a little bit more work to upload the files. Check out @gihanchanuka's answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload

Comment: @PGHE The problem is postman uses file location to read the file 'files = {'user_image': open('C://file.jpg', 'rb')}' . Is there a way to do this when using flask form OR When using images in POST request, is there no way we can make it work in both flask and postman?

Answer (score 2):

```
api_url = "https://34.35.36.37:8000/api"

class UploadForm(FlaskForm):
    user_image = FileField('Upload an image',validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'], u'Image only!'), FileRequired(u'File was empty!')])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    form = UploadForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        file_uploaded = request.files['user_image']
        files = {'user_image': (file_uploaded.filename, file_uploaded.read())}
        response = requests.post(api_url, files = files)
        return 'some text'

     return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

The above code worked for me. It is equivalent to sending a 'POST' request from postman after selecting a file in 'Body' section with key 'user_image'. Do not use any headers in the post request `response = requests.post(api_url, files = files)`

On the server side(api_url), the file can be received with `user_image = request.files['user_image']`

Comment: Headers can be used but they should be configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to have debug mode set to false on both applications.