# Locust Test payload with files

Tags: python, api, load-testing, locust, fastapi

this is my first question and I would like to know how to send the following test parameters to my FastAPI API:

```
to: (string)
name: (string)
files: (array)
```

what is the correct syntax? I am trying with the following:

```py
self.client.post ("/ email", dict (to = "", name = "", files = "hi.pdf"))
```

Comment: As per https://docs.locust.io/en/v0.5.1/writing-a-locustfile.html, it looks correct(other than the space after the slash). You may want to modify it to
from locust import ResponseError

with self.client.post("/email", dict (to = "", name = "", files = "hi.pdf")}, catch_response=True) as response:
    if response.data == "fail":
        raise ResponseError("Failed to post")

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Locust doc on `post` requests. https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.clients.HttpSession.post

Locust's http classes are based on [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file). There are [multiple ways to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567429/7355637). One way is to read file directly and post it by itself:

```
with open("hi.pdf", "rb") as hi:
    self.client.post("/email", data=hi.read())
```

I'm not familiar with FastAPI so I don't know where your `to` and `name` need to go. If they're headers, you can do:

```
with open("hi.pdf", "rb") as hi:
    self.client.post("/email", data=hi.read(), headers={"to": "", "name": ""})
```