# How to specify a file in the 'filebody' in Python API post request?

Tags: python, api, post, import, sendinblue

I am trying to post a file to sendinblue using API in Python and struggling with what to put instead of "dataset1". It works if I manually type the file contents but not if I specify a file - I have tried csv, json, txt formats but nothing works. The error message says 'We could not find any valid email or SMS in the file you uploaded', I think it doesn't like the 'filebody' format.

My code below:
Any help greatly appreciated!

```
import requests

url = "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts/import"

payload = {
    "listIds": [12],
    "emailBlacklist": False,
    "smsBlacklist": False,
    "updateExistingContacts": True,
    "emptyContactsAttributes": False,
    "fileBody": "dataset1"

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "api-key": "APIKEY"
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)


        
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python requests file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If not you can try some of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload) solutions.

```
files = {'upload_file': open('file.txt','rb')}
url = "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts/import"
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "api-key": "APIKEY"
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you. Where should I specify the headers (API key) in this code?

Comment: I added the headers, @IrinaObrazcova

Comment: I have tried this code now and it gives me a 'Response [400]' ...

Comment: You need to replace `APIKEY` with your key. You can read the docs here https://apidocs.sendinblue.com/authentication/

Comment: I am already using my API key in the code..

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `fileUrl` instead of `fileBody` which can be referenced from [here](https://developers.sendinblue.com/reference#importcontacts-1).
You mentioned that if you type the contents manually, then it works fine. So, please try to use the url(which is publicly accessible) for `fileUrl` parameter in the request and let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is a way to convert a csv file into raw URL link in Python? (without going through Github and doing it manually)

Comment: I think you will need to save the csv file in github or any other cloud to make it accessible by Sendinblue’s servers. So, you will need to pass the Url to that file in your request. And once your contacts have been imported, you can remove the file.

Comment: Yes with github the problem is I have to manually upload the file and convert it but I need this to be an automatic process. I have also tried to create a URL link from the OneDrive but that's not working either..

Comment: How often do you plan on importing the contacts?

Comment: If you don’t intent to do it very often, I will suggest you to create and upload the file manually. But in case you need to do it often, you can try using AWS S3, which should solve your purpose. You will need to create the csv as you are doing now and then save it on S3. Then, you can use that url for your body request.