# How to communicate between 2 Django separate projects?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two separate Django projects and want to locate them in 2 different servers. Is there a way to communicate with each other? In one projects I need to be able to upload a file and send it to second project for processing.

Answer (score 0):

It's called service discovery. read more about it here: https://microservices.io/patterns/server-side-discovery.html

Answer (score 0):

basically you can just use [python request library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/):

```py
import request

files = {'upload_file': open('file.txt','rb')}
values = {'DB': 'photcat', 'OUT': 'csv', 'SHORT': 'short'}

r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=values)
```

and the response from the other server can be for example json with urls to the files, or something...
check [python requests file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload)

but be careful, you should send some hashes/keys or something so other people can't imitate the behavior and send you false data. That ofc depends on what you need it for