# How do I troubleshoot "Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable"?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm sending form data and images in a POST request to my backend:

```
data = {
        'username': self.ids['username'].text,
        'email': self.email_field.text,
        'password': self.ids['password'].text,
        'data': json.dumps({
            'first_photo': open(f'{self.selfies_path}/first.png', 'rb'),
            'second_photo': open(f'{self.selfies_path}/second.png', 'rb'),
            'third_photo': open(f'{self.selfies_path}/third.png', 'rb')
        })
      }
response = requests.post('http://5.10.203.170/auth/register', files=data)
```

The above throws `python  :  TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable`

How can I make it work ?

Comment: why are you trying to assign an entire file (returned from `open`) to a json key? Consider only sending the path to the file instead, the frontend should be able to serve it

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload) answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

You can change your file to base64

Answer (score -1):

I went with:

```
data = {
        'first_photo': open(f'{self.selfies_path}/first.png', 'rb'),
        'second_photo': open(f'{self.selfies_path}/second.png', 'rb'),
        'third_photo': open(f'{self.selfies_path}/third.png', 'rb'),
        'data': json.dumps({
            'username': self.ids['username'].text,
            'email': self.email_field.text,
            'password': self.ids['password'].text
        })
      }
response = requests.post('http://5.10.203.170/auth/register', files=data)
```

Answer (score -1):

convert bytes into base64 and decrypt it in your website code