# CURL command in Python's requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

Can you please help me convert the following CURL command into a command for Python's requests library?

```
curl -F pdb_file[pathvar]=@/path/myfile.pdb -X POST https://proteins.plus/api/pdb_files_rest -H "Accept: application/json"
```

I've tried many things, like this:

```
import requests
file = open("3w32.pdb", "rb")
url = "https://proteins.plus/api/pdb_files_rest"
response = requests.post(url, data=file)
response.json()
```

or this:

```
import requests
file = open("3w32.pdb", "rb")
url = "https://proteins.plus/api/pdb_files_rest"
response = requests.post(url, data={"pdb_file[pathvar]": file}, json={"Accept": "application/json"})
response.json()
```

but I can't make it work. I either get an error from the server, or a JSONDecodeError in Python.

Comment: import requests
file = open("3w32.pdb", "rb")
url = "https://proteins.plus/api/pdb_files_rest"
response = requests.post(test_url, data=file)
response.json()



In this change test_url to url   and are you sure you want to read the file in binary mode ? with "rb" option ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python requests file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload)

Comment: @AlokRaj oh sorry I had pasted it wrong, but I'm executing it the way you said. I've updated the code in the question.

Comment: Wrote an answer, please let me know if that works for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve it at last.
The problem was that the 'pdb_file[pathvar]' part in the curl command should've been added to the request, like this:

```
import requests
file = open("3w32.pdb", "rb")
url = "https://proteins.plus/api/pdb_files_rest"
response = requests.post(url, files={'pdb_file[pathvar]':file})
response.json()
```

Now it works!

Comment: Nice :) Happy that you got the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567429/4252013
Instead of using "data" argument try with "file"

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you have only opened the file and passed the pointer. you can pass the file contents by having `file.read()` in place.

Please refer this block of code:

```
import requests
file = open("3w32.pdb", "rb")
url = "https://proteins.plus/api/pdb_files_rest"
response = requests.post(url, data=file.read())
response.json()
```

Comment: Thank you, but that did not solve the issue. I'm still getting an error from the server: {'status_code': 'bad_request',
 'message': 'Invalid number of parameters or incorrect parameter name'}