# Send files to flask endpoints in python

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Given a flask server, I wish to `mimic` an HTTP request to it from another python file, it it possible?
I.e
Given the following python "client" application:

```
def send_img_to_flask(img_path,server_ip):
    request = Request(ip=server_ip,POST_parameters={'file':img_path})
```

And respectively the server endpoint will:

```
@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
      return 'file uploaded successfully'
```

Comment: Do you mean displaying files on the flask route or uploading files?

Comment: How about you use requests library in the other python file, like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567429/6180150

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857411/7034613 this answers exactly what I was looking for, thanks!