# How to send a PDF file by DRF

Tags: python, api, pdf, django-rest-framework

I have a request for you, can you please help me with one question.
How can I send a pdf file via api.
It starts like this, they send me the base64 format and I accept it and do the decoding.
Then I need to send this file to another endpoint, but I just can’t put it there. Could you please help me

[image]
According to Postman, my file sits quietly and works as it should. The picture shows that it takes the form-date.

> 

```
def sendDocs(photoBack):
    try:
        headers = {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data;', 
                   'bsauth': 'key'}
        import base64
        decodedData = base64.b64decode((photoBack))
        pdfFile = open('photoBack.pdf', 'rb+')
        pdfFile.write(decodedData)
        pdfFile.close()
        response = HttpResponse(pdfFile, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="photoBack.pdf"'
        url = f'https://file.shinhanfinance.kz/files/shinhanfinance/add?client={1013246509}'
        files = {"file":response}
        firstPost1 = requests.post(url,data =response,headers=headers)
        print(Response(firstPost1))
        return Response({firstPost1})
     
    except:
        return Response({'bruh what wrong ?'})
```

Here my code

Answer (score 0):

```
def sendDocs(photoBack):
    try:
        headers = {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data;', 
                   'bsauth': 'key'}
        import base64
        decodedData = base64.b64decode((photoBack))
        pdfFile = open('photoBack.pdf', 'rb+')
        pdfFile.write(decodedData)
        pdfFile.close()
        response = HttpResponse(pdfFile, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="photoBack.pdf"'
        url = f'https://file.shinhanfinance.kz/files/shinhanfinance/add?client={1013246509}'
        files = {"file":response}
        firstPost1 = requests.post(url,data =response,headers=headers)
        print(Response(firstPost1))
        return Response({firstPost1})
     
    except:
        return Response({'bruh what wrong ?'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use decodedData, and put it into file parameters.

```
firstPost1 = requests.post(url, files={"file": decodedData}, headers=headers)
```

I think here is your solution [How to upload file with python requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/how-to-upload-file-with-python-requests)

Comment: i tryed, doesnt work

Comment: And which error do you have?

Comment: File not found, i cant understand what is wrong

Comment: pdfFile = open('photoBack.pdf', 'rb+'), just try to use 'wb' mode

Comment: Same doesnt work

Comment: Try use 
firstPost1 = requests.post(url,files={'file': decodedData}, headers=headers)