# Convert curl to python requests (upload file)

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have an example of curl request:

```
curl -X "POST" "http://192.168.24.62:8080/upload" \
     -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8' \
     -F "file=@test.wav" \
     -F "filename=buffer.wav"
```

And it works well. I want to convert this request using `requests` library in python. Here is my try:

```
import requests

filename = 'test.wav'

url = 'http://192.168.24.62:8080/upload'
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    files = {'file': ('buffer.wav', file, 'audio/wav')}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8'}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)

print(response.json())
```

I get an error:

```
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Code looks good. Could be an error on `192.168.24.62:8080/upload`'s end, if you have access check the logs?

Comment: Also try changing `audio/wav` with `multipart/form-data`, try the `print(requests.Request('POST', 'http://example.com', files=files).prepare().body.decode('ascii'))` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/how-to-upload-file-with-python-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is working on my machine (different IP:port obviously).

```
import requests

url = "http://192.168.24.62:8080/upload"

with open('test.wav', 'rb') as f:
    files = {
        'file': (f.name, f, 'audio/wav'),
        'filename': ('', 'buffer.wav')
    }

    response = requests.post(url, files=files)


print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to put the 'filename' on the 'files' dict. Try something like:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8',
}

files = {
    'file': open('test.wav', 'rb'),
    'filename': (None, 'buffer.wav'),
}

response = requests.post('http://192.168.24.62:8080/upload', headers=headers, files=files)
```

Comment: `files = {'file': ('buffer.wav', file, 'audio/wav')}` the first element sets the new filename, the second is the file to upload and the third sets the Content-Type header.