# Python requests returns 503 status code as response when sending a file through POST request

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, flask, python-requests

So I am using python requests to send a post request to another server (both servers are internal to the company). It worked some weeks ago, but I tried today and it has suddenly stopped working.

I can use postman to send the same request and the server responds with 201. I can perform a get request from my python code using requests library.

The problem ONLY occurs on post request from python code.

Here's the piece:

```
with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
        # f is a file-like object. 
        data = {"name": experiment_id + ".zip", "content": f}
        #The CALCSCORE_URL is an env variable named CALCSCORE_BE set up in each environment.
        calcscore_url = f"{settings.CALCSCORE_URL}/api/hive/experiment/{experiment_id}/roi" 
        response = requests.post(calcscore_url, files=data)
```

I tried different things, like sending the data in a separate 'files' and 'data' argument but its always the same error.
The file is 5 MB in size. I don't think its that big?

`response.content` shows `response timed out`.

Comment: That's the wrong way to upload files with requests.  I don't see how it ever worked.  Why are you doing it that way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload file with python requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/how-to-upload-file-with-python-requests)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari With this, its the same error.

Comment: @JohnGordon what is wrong with the OP?

Comment: @JohnGordon This worked, and it still works. Its just that something was wrong with the file and the receiving server went to infinite loop so didn't return a response. Now that i tried a different file, it works.

Comment: Oh, now I see that the code uses `request.post()`, not `requests.post()`.  The code does not define `request`, so I'll just assume you're using it correctly.  Why did you say that it uses `requests` when it actually doesn't?

Comment: @JohnGordon It is 'requests'. I just made a mistake in the code while writing here. Fixing it. But I am using requests, ant no request.