# curl to python code conversion unpredicted error

Tags: python, curl

I'm trying to send a picture to a server I've made, now the problem is that the following curl code from terminal:

```
curl -X POST -F 'file=@path' -F 'delete_image=yes' url
```

where path is the absolute path of the image and url is url of the server

The problem is this code (that should be the exact tranlation in python is not working and it's returning an error 400 "bad request"

```
files = [
     ('file', open('/Users/viewermac_1/Desktop/Testbed_Web/test.png','rb')),
     ('delete_image', 'yes'),
]

test = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Update: Putting delete_image as data works, but I'm not receiving anything back from the server (I'm supposed to receive a link)

Comment: `('delete_image', 'yes')` isn't a file. Maybe you should pass that part to [**`data`**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Comment: pass delete_image to data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading files using requests and send extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015166/uploading-files-using-requests-and-send-extra-data)

Comment: but the terminal code works even if the delete_image is a -F

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code :

```
import requests

files = {
    'file': ('path', open('/Users/viewermac_1/Desktop/Testbed_Web/test.png', 'rb')),
    'delete_image': (None, 'yes'),
}

response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```